# Is there an equivalent of SQL NULLIF function in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, null, nullif

Is there an equivalent of [SQL NULLIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) function built-in within c#?

Example of what it could look like :

```
double? result
double denominator = 0;
double Numerator = 100;
result = Numerator / NullIf(denominator, 0);
result = Numerator / denominator.NullIf(0);
result = Numerator / Object.NullIf(denominator, 0);
```

Comment: You meant for the denominator to be nullable and not the result right?

Comment: I mean to divide by NULL when the value is zero

Comment: just use ternary operator for result. `result = denominator == 0 ? (double?)null : Numberator/denomiantor;`

Comment: Also consider that double.NaN behaves much like sql null here, and dosn't require nullables et al.  1 / NaN = NaN etc which is I think what you are looking for, you could easily add your own NaNIf extension function.

Comment: Thanks, for pointing that out. However I will stick to NULL since not all type have NaN. For exemple, integer doesn't have NaN. I prefer to use the same pattern every.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is no language feature for this at present.

You can easily get the same result, either with a ternary if:

```
result = Numerator / (denominator == 0 ? (double?)null : denomiantor);
```

Or even wrapping it as a generic function, so something like:

```
Nullable<T> NullIf<T>(T left, T right)
{
    return left == right ? (T?)null : left;
}
```

which could then be called like:

```
result = Numerator / NullIf(denominator, 0);
```

Comment: It works but I really don't like operations on `int?` ,  `double?` etc. imho `5/null == null` is confusing.

Comment: @vittore Seems straight forward to me if you think of `null` as meaning unknown value.  5 divided by an unknown value is an unknown value.

Comment: Not worth of it's own answer as yours is acceptable, but it could also be an extension method to be more c#'y although it doesn't exactly mirror the SQL variant
`
public static class Extensions
{
    public Nullable<T> NullIf<T>(this T left, T right) => left == right ? (T?)null : left;
}
...
result = numerator / denominator.NullIf(0)`

Answer (score 7):

Accepted answer give me:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'

My working example of NULLIF:

```
public static T? NullIf<T>(T left, T right) where T : struct
{
    return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(left, right) ? (T?)null : left;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No but you could create one.

```
public static Nullable<T> NullIf<T>(T first, T second) where T : struct
{
    if(first == second)
        return new Nullable<T>();
    return new Nullable<T>(first);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no. but you can use ternary operator for compact way of writing it:

```
double? result
double denominator = 0;
double Numerator = 100;
result = denominator == 0 ? (double?)null : Numerator / denominator;
```

However there is equivalent of IFNULL:

```
result = x ?? 0;
```

equivalent of:

```
result = x.HasValue? x.Value : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do we assume this extension method is able to know what is null in our context.

Its the responsibility of the context that calls it.
Therefore is a mistake of saying only one value will be considered null as all the response in this thread impliy.

```
public static T? NullIf<T>(this T value, Func<T,bool> isConsideredNull) 
{
        if(value == null)
        {
           return null;
        }
        return isConsideredNull(value) ? (T?)null : value;
}
```

We would use it the following way

```
string test = "NULL";

test.NullIf((x)=> x.Equals("NULL"));
test.NullIf((x)=> x == "NULL");
test.NullIf((x)=> x.Equals("NULL",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```